# SwiftUI Drag&Drop: Accessing the dragged item in validateDrop

Tags: swiftui, drag-and-drop

G'day everyone,

I'm trying to interrogate the dragged object during the validate phase of drag and drop in SwiftUI, but haven't been able to make it work. Here's my validateDrop method:

```
func validateDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
    print("Drop Validating")
    print ("Dropping into slot where  \(rosterPlayer!.givenName!) \(rosterPlayer!.surname!) is")


    guard info.hasItemsConforming(to: [PlayerShirtUTT.uti.identifier]) else {
        return false
    }

    let itemProviders = info.itemProviders(for: [PlayerShirtUTT.uti.identifier])
        guard let itemProvider = itemProviders.first
    else {
        return false
    }
    print ("Lets check")
    
    itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: Player.self) { player, _ in
        let player = player as? Player
        // Do the player checks here
        print ("Player check code")
    }
    return true
}
```

Exactly the same code in my performDrop method works fine... can anyone point me in the right direction here please?

Comment: Any update on this? Seems ridiculously difficult to determine this.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else is looking for an answer to this, the answer is you can't.

Documentation reference:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/drag_and_drop/making_a_view_into_a_drop_destination

The content of the dragged item is only available asynchronously after the drop is concluded (i.e. only in perdormDrop() ).

So, now I'm looking at ways to use the UTT as a distinguishing identifier for the same base data.

Comment: Could you use teamData for this, I wonder? Apple doesn't really document what that is for.

Comment: WWDC2017 has a session Data Delivery with Drag and Drop that explains teamData. You have up to 8K of data there to use how you want. This data is persisted in a drag in your own app and between apps from your team, but not third parties.